# What skill does game development require?

Tags: game-development

Does being a game developer require more specific skills than a normal programmer ? 
I found that some developers know graphic design and 3D motion etc... so they can work on full projects by themselves ....

so what is really needed to build a good foundation as a game developer ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Very good question. I've been asking myself the same questions. That's why I did a deep research to get good answers. 
Let's start this way. The most known project by a single developer is LSA (Lost soul aside) which is not even released, but the game developer claims that he did everything by himself. He is a designer. I've checked other projects as well. Every good single project has been made by a designer. So if you are a designer, you can develop a game yourself. If your a programmer without the design talent, I recommend a team work. If your asking yourself how is it possible that a designer can create a good game. The answer is simple. Game development with existing game engines (UE - Unreal engine) for example, is so simplified that you don't even need to use any programming language. You're just playing with objects and when you get the feeling, you can do a real masterpiece there.

Comment: I thought of a similar conclusion myself but i felt game dev. is more than that in terms of skills .... I talked to people from the industry who studied some human psychology which could relate to the concept of "Level Design" 
so yeah I agree that engines saved a lot of coding effort and etc.. 
but still there is some skills that are needed beside design ... what do you think ?

Comment: Of course there are others skills needed as well, but these skills are really easy to learn. I have a few friends which are designers and they are creating really wonderfull games. They didn't complete any school or lesson... They also claim how easy it is to create a game... If your not talented for designing, it makes things very complicated... Designing is more talent then practice...